# Multiple inner joins using laravel and translation

Tags: laravel, join, laravel-translatable

I have problem using translatable library, I am trying to sort the companies by name, so as written in the doc, I need to use inner joins, I tried this code, everything is good but the data is messed up when I add voucher_translations, its like it get from different table or records, I dont know what I am doing wrong :(

```
$vouchers = Voucher::join('company_translations', 'vouchers.company_id', '=', 'company_translations.company_id')
    ->join('voucher_translations', 'voucher_translations.voucher_id', '=', 'vouchers.id')
    ->where('company_translations.locale', '=', 'en');
    ->where('voucher_translations.locale', '=', 'en')
    ->orderBy('company_translations.name', 'asc');
```

Comment: Is there `->get()` after `->orderBy('company_translations.name', 'asc')`?

Comment: yes of course, the data is there but its messed up

Comment: I suppose there can be overwrited your main table `id` by other table `id` when you use `join`, so you can try something like that: `->get('voucher.*') `.

Comment: I cant add parameter to get :/

Comment: what is wrong why you can't?

Comment: theres no parameter to the function get(), do you mean select() ?

Comment: You can pass parametrs to 'get' or to 'select' as you want.